# How to change URL parameter using transparent proxy

Tags: apache-2.2, proxy, routing, http, rewrite

I have a subnet of computers connected to Internet through a router (which could be a HTTP proxy as well).

My goal is to change URL parameter for a one single URL.

If users go to http://www.google.com/ or to http://www.google.com/?hl=en, in both cases they should see content from http://www.google.com/?hl=fr

Is it possible to do this using url rewriting in apache config? What other approaches could become the easiest way to achieve the goal?

**Update:** google.com is used just an example, that's not the case.

Comment: This is a really bad idea. How am I supposed to get English, then? If I wanted français, I would have chosen it myself!

Comment: It wouldn't be transparent if it was altering the request.

Comment: google.com is used just an example

Answer (score 1):

You can use SQUID, which is a more commonly used as a proxy, to accomplish what you are attempting.  The [`url_rewrite_program`](http://www.squid-cache.org/Doc/config/url_rewrite_program/) option allows for requests to be sent to a script for rewriting.

The following script would substitute the url in the manor you describe:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

while (<>) {
        @line = split;
        $_ = $line[0];

        if (m|http://google.com/\?hl=en|) {
                # do some replacement work
                $_ =~s|\?hl=en|\?hl=fr|g;
                print $_,"\n";
        } else {
                # send the request directly
                print $_;
        }
}
```

If you prefer to use apache, it sounds like it can be done with a combination of `mod_proxy` and `mod_rewrite`.  See [this page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/proxy.html) on apache.org for a tutorial.